# Shiny : add a new element when clicking a button

Tags: r, shiny

I want to print a tagList() with a textInput and a textAreaInput in a ModalDialog.

Then in this ModalDialog, I want to append a new element with a textInput and a textAreaInput by clicking a "+" icon, increasing the ID number to 1.

The first element (with ID 0) is well created with tagAppendChild when the ModalDialog appears but clicking the "+" icon doesn't add a second element using the observeEvent and tagAppendChild on my defined tagList.

Here is a reproducible Shiny code.

Any clue ? Thanx

```
ui <- fluidPage(   
        actionButton("open", "Modal") 
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
    count <- reactiveVal(0) 
    my_list <- tagList()   
    observeEvent(input$open, {
        count(0)
        showModal(modalDialog(
          tagAppendChild(my_list, add_item(count())),
          actionButton(inputId = "add_entry", style = "border: 0px", label = NULL, icon("circle-plus")),
          footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"), actionButton("Ok", "OK"))
        ))   
    })

  add_item <- function(count) {
    return(
      tagList(
        textInput(width=164, paste0("add_id",count), paste("ID", count()), placeholder="Only numbers allowed"),
        textAreaInput(width=400, height=100, paste0("add_comment",count), "Comments")
      )
    )   
  }

  observeEvent(input$add_entry, {
    count(count()+1)
    tagAppendChild(my_list, add_item(count()))   
  }) 
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `shiny::insertUI` to do this. Here I create a div inside the Modal with the id "modal_ui" that we'll use later to tell insertUI where I want to insert the ui.

```
  observeEvent(input$add_entry, {
    count(count() + 1)
    insertUI(selector = "#modal_ui", ui = add_item(count()))
  })
```

App:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  my_list <- tagList()
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    count(0)
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        div(
          id = "modal_ui",
          add_item(count())
        ),
        actionButton(
          inputId = "add_entry",
          style   = "border: 0px",
          label   = NULL,
          icon("circle-plus")
        ),
        footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"), actionButton("Ok", "OK"))
      )
    )
  })

  add_item <- function(count) {
    div(
      id = paste0("div_", count),
      textInput(
        inputId     = paste0("add_id", count),
        label       = paste("ID", count()),
        width       = 164,
        placeholder = "Only numbers allowed"
      ),
      textAreaInput(width = 400, height = 100, paste0("add_comment", count), "Comments")
    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$add_entry, {
    count(count() + 1)
    insertUI(selector = "#modal_ui", ui = add_item(count()))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanx, it works like a charm, I didn't remember that insertUI exists, it's a good thing to know it !